# How to deserialize multiple objects present in a single serialized file in c#?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have multiple "command objects" serialized on a single file. I need to get those objects back by deserializing so that I could replay those commands. Please, help me do this.

Comment: What kind of serialization are you using -- XmlSerializer, BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter, WCF, something else? Can you show your serialization code?

Comment: Ah, duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817641/i-have-a-single-file-and-need-to-serialize-multiple-objects-randomly-how-can-iin

Comment: Is this related to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814191/how-to-serialize-multiple-objects-of-the-same-class-into-a-single-file-and-deseia
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817641/i-have-a-single-file-and-need-to-serialize-multiple-objects-randomly-how-can-iin
?

Comment: I think this should be closed and merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817641/ - they are the same thing.

Comment: For info, my answer to this question is now part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817641/

Answer (score 0):

I never use the stock serializer for persistent store. I find it works for remoting just fine, but I don't want my file formats bound to .NET framework.

Comment: I'll second that - but I'm not sure how that helps with the question?

Comment: I'm suggesting he may want to reconsider his plan of serializing things to a file.